# Does a Canon 1.4X I teleconverter provide the information needed to show up in Lightroom?

Tags: canon, lightroom, metadata, teleconverter

I'm looking at buying a 1.4X Mark I teleconverter (I already have a Tamron one that doesn't register) and was just wondering if anyone knows if the Canon Mark I makes itself known in the metadata

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When using a teleconverter on a Canon DSLR, what happens to EXIF data?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45118/when-using-a-teleconverter-on-a-canon-dslr-what-happens-to-exif-data)

Comment: I understand all of that I just want confirmation that the mark I is new enough to register

Comment: The Mark II and III are much better optically.I would strongly encourage you to consider one of those if optical quality is important to you.

Comment: Not to mention that the original 100-400 doesn't really have the optical quality to begin with to take converters well. http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/ISO-12233-Sample-Crops.aspx?Lens=113&Camera=453&Sample=0&FLI=8&API=2&LensComp=0&CameraComp=0&SampleComp=0&FLIComp=0&APIComp=0

Comment: What do you mean "register" in Lightroom.

Comment: @mattdm I don't think the question is if the teleconverter is "too new" as of March of 2016. I think the OP was asking if the tele was "new enough" (i.e., not too outdated) to show up in EXIF metadata.

Comment: @scottbb Ohhhh, I see that. Okay, sure. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a Canon 7D mk II, 70-200mm F2.8 II, and the 2x Extender III and when I import the images into Lightroom 5, I noticed that Lightroom Library mode does allow me to filter for using the lens with the extender. I get "EF70-200mm f/2.8L IS II USM +2x III" for the metadata and filtering options but when I go to Development mode, the Lens Corrections will only correct for the 70-200mm without the option of the 2x Extender. Now I know your asking about the 1.4x Extender with the 100-400mm but I suspect with the Canon lens and Canon Extender, the metadata in Lightroom will show the similar information as the 70-200 with 2x Extender.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may not be with your existing teleconverter. It is most likely the way that Adobe products ignore most of the "maker notes" section of the EXIF information. The additional information about the TC and the resulting difference in focal length and aperture is almost certainly contained in the "maker notes" section rather than in the other standardized fields of the EXIF info.

Have you tried viewing the EXIF info via Canon's *Digital Photo Professional* to see if it properly shows up there?

Comment: I just spent 15 minutes trying to figure out DPP (note you need a cr2 not a dng duh me) and then checked with a test image no change in focal length or note that the teleconverter existed

Comment: If you are converting to DNG the adobe convertor is stripping out all of the "maker notes" from the EXIF info.

Comment: It won't show the non-Canon TC listed with the lens used, but should show the accurate focal length: i.e when shooting at 200mm and max aperture w/ my 70-200mm f/2.8 lens + 2X Kenko TC (That is an exact copy of a Tamron 2X available at the same time) it shows the focal length and aperture as 400mm f/5.6.

Comment: Of course there are several different Tamron/Kenko/whatever other name gets put on them varieties that have been sold over the years. They've usually offered two tiers at any point in time. The lower tier only has 4 or 5 elements in 4 groups, the upper tier has 7 elements in 4 groups.